# Three.js collision detection (ERROR)

Tags: html, web, three.js, webgl

Im trying to make a collision detection "program" in Three.js (WEBGL library).
However, Im getting an error "cannot call method multiplyvector3 of undefined".

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

The function for collision detection I just implemented, is:

```
function animate() {

      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      render();
        for (var vertexIndex = 0; geometries[0].vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
        {       
            var localVertex = geometries[0].vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
            var globalVertex = geometries[0].matrix.multiplyVector3(localVertex);
            var directionVector = globalVertex.subSelf(meshes[5].position);

            var ray = new THREE.Ray( meshes[5].position, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
            var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( meshes);
            if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
            {
            }
            else {
                meshes[5].position.y -= 0.15;
                meshes[5].rotation.z -= 0.15;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the full code is,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r54/three.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var camera, scene, renderer, material;
var meshes = new Array();
var geometries = new Array();
init();
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 500;
  camera.position.x += 125;
  scene.add(camera);

  geometries[0] = new THREE.CubeGeometry(35, 35, 35);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  geometries[1] = new THREE.SphereGeometry(35, 35, 35);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();    
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         meshes[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometries[0], material);   
    }

    meshes[5] = new THREE.Mesh(geometries[1], material);

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
         meshes[i].position.x = (35*i);
         meshes[i].rotation.x = 5;
    }

    meshes[5].position.y = (100);

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
        scene.add(meshes[i]);
    }
        scene.add(meshes[5]);


  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
    for (var vertexIndex = 0; geometries[0].vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
    {       
        var localVertex = geometries[0].vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
        var globalVertex = geometries[0].matrix.multiplyVector3(localVertex);
        var directionVector = globalVertex.subSelf(meshes[5].position);

        var ray = new THREE.Ray( meshes[5].position, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
        var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( meshes);
        if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
        {
        }
        else {
            meshes[5].position.y -= 0.15;
            meshes[5].rotation.z -= 0.15;
        }
    }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
}//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are using a version of the three.js library that is a year old. Update to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var vertexIndex = 0; geometries[0].vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
```

should be

```
for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < geometries[0].vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
```

Comment: Sorry, right answer is; the three.js functions are deprecated, I will try find them, but thanks either way;)